# Calculating the probability that demographic trends happened by chance

Tags: probability, data-mining, categorical-data

I ran an ad campaign on Facebook and I have impressions (ad-views), clicks, and sign-ups broken down by gender and age.

Certain demographics have a higher rate of clicks and sign-ups when compared to their respective percent of impressions. What is the best way to determine if these differences represent significant results instead of random noise?

I am trying to see how age and gender predict sign-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really clear what you are trying to predict, but let's suppose you want to investigate how sign-ups relate to gender and age.

Well you either sign-up or your don't, i.e. it's a binary variable. So you could try [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression). That's would allow you to predict the probability of signing up give the persons gender and age (and anything else you have).

Answer (score 1):

If you're relatively new to statistics, logistic regression can be pretty difficult to master.  An alternative plan would consist of...

- a *T*-test of the age difference between those who do and don't click (or sign up);
- a Chi-Square test of the independence of clicks (or sign ups) and gender.